# Running two docker containers on one Azure App service plan

Tags: containers, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I have two containers that need to run on the same machine.
The first container is the server and the second one is the agent.
*Server image tag name: local-wptserver
Server image tag name: local-wptagent*

I can get it to work locally so I am trying to deploy it to the cloud (Azure) for the team's consumption.

This is how I am running it locally::

```
docker run -d -p 4000:80 local-wptserver

docker run -d -p 4001:80 --network="host" -e "SERVER_URL=http://localhost:4000/work/" -e "LOCATION=EastUS_wptdriver" local-wptagent
```

This basically sets up the server and the agent to talk to each other so once I start making API calls to the server it schedules the job with the agent and returns me the results.

However since my images are now in Azure Container registry, how do I get the container to instantiate with those extra parameters (--network="host" -e "SERVER_URL=http://localhost:4000/work/" -e "LOCATION=EastUS_wptdriver") when it gets deployed to a web app?
Is this something I can add in the docker file, prior to creating the image? If yes, how?

Note: I am using the same Azure app service plan to ensure that the two web apps (built form two different repositories in the Azure container registry: server and agent) are on the same machine.

Comment: What do you think when you do not give any update and also do not accept the answer? Do you still want to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to deploy multiple containers in the Azure Web App, then you need to use the docker-compose file to deploy the multiple containers. You can follow the steps in the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app).

And then, the --network does not support in the docker-compose in Azure Web App, you can see all supported compose options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#docker-compose-options). But don't worry, the containers can communicate with each other through the ports.

According to the message that you push the images to Azure Container Registry. Then you should use the ACR as the docker registry. So you need to set the environment variables for your ACR and the details [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#ACRSettings). And there are also many details you cloud know in the link I provided.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers Charles.
This is what my docker-compose.yml looks like::

version: '3'
services:
    webpagetestserver:
        image: "local-wptserver"
        ports: 
            - "4000:80"
        
    webpagetestagent:
        image: "local-wptagent"
        ports: 
            - "4001:80"
        
I have not specified the network=host since that is not supported, which I fear is causing my agents to not connect to the server. Any work-arounds?

Comment: @SrayanGuhathakurta You need to read the support docker compose options more carefully. The port does not support the ports except 80 and 8080. You only need to set the port as `ports: - "80"`. And you can use the environment variables as the tutorial shows you in the example link.

Comment: @SrayanGuhathakurta What about the question? Do you solve it?

Comment: Hi Charles, Thanks for the feedback. I did try changing ports: - "4000:80" and ports: - "4001:80" to just ports: - "80" and that did not work.
Also I set the env variables and uploaded the images to ACR and created a docker-compose.yml file which works fine for me on my localmachine but not on the webapp.
Regarding the --network parameter I found out that you can use network_mode: "host" in your docker-compose.yml file

Comment: @SrayanGuhathakurta Do you really read the info which I provided in the answer?! The `network` option was not supported in the docker-compose file for Web App.

Comment: Instead of going back on forth why don't you tell me how you would write the Dockerfile? I think that would be a lot more helpful.

Comment: @SrayanGuhathakurta I do not have all the information about what you need to do, you need to create the docker-compose file yourself. What I can do is only to figure out and correct the mistake that you made.